# Access localhost ( running on Mac OS X ) from another machine in the network

Tags: macos, rest, networking, localhost

I have a REST service running on Mac OS X, which im currently accessing using "**localhost:8888**" and "**10.0.2.2:8888**"

I want to access the same service from another computer which is in the same network.

I disabled the firewall also and I typed

```
 nc -v 192.168.1.3 8888
```

and got the result as

```
nc: connectx to 192.168.1.3 port 8888 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

currently i use localhost (to access using java application) and 10.0.2.2 (to access using android application runs in the simulator) which both runs on the same machine which the server runs too.

I want to put the android application to my phone and give the machine ip addess ( because if i connect to internet via wifi, it'll be in the same local area network) i should be able to access my service runs on my machine.

can some one please tell me what im doing wrong here? Thank you

Comment: It is not clear what is the IP address of the server. Is it 10.0.2.2 or 192.168.1.3 (or both), or are the different IPs here by mistake.

Comment: Hi pajaja, I added a explanation as an edit for the post so the other people wont get confused. Can you please check the post if its not a pain? Thank you :)

Comment: Hi @RaminduDeSilva - were you able to figure out a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access localhost from your front end code. It needs to refer to the server's name or address.

Answer (score 0):

The localhost address should be `127.0.0.1`, which is in the loopback range of addresses. Any address in the `127.0.0.0/8` block can never appear anywhere on any network, nor can any address in that block be used as a source or destination address outside a host. It is not possible for one host to access anything in that address range on another host.

The goes back at least as far as [*RFC 990, ASSIGNED NUMBERS*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc990):

> The class A network number 127 is assigned the "loopback" function,
> that is, a datagram sent by a higher level protocol to a network 127
> address should loop back inside the host.  No datagram "sent" to a
> network 127 address should ever appear on any network anywhere.

[*RFC 1122, Requirements for Internet Hosts -- Communication Layers*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#section-3.2.1.3):

> (g)  { 127,  }
>
> Internal host loopback address.  Addresses of this form MUST NOT
> appear outside a host.

Also [*RFC 3330, Special-Use IPv4 Addresses*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc333):

> 127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host loopback address.  A datagram sent by a higher level protocol to an
> address anywhere within this block should loop back inside the host.
> This is ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback,
> but no addresses within this block should ever appear on any network
> anywhere [RFC1700, page 5].